# Execution plan information from drools

Tags: drools

We are planning to use BRMS 5.3.1 in our projects and one use case popped up yesterday where business wanted to store what rules evaulated to TRUE and were eventually fired.  this is so that these information can be used for analysis purposes at a later point. Does Drools provide an API(s) that could provide this information at runtime? If it does, what would be the performance impact of having such a feature enabled on production systems?
Appreciate your answers on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah you can add one of the AgendaListeners to the session to get which rules were activated and fired. The performance impact will depend on what you do inside that listener, but if you implement an async way (sending a jms message for example) to store the information provided by the listener everything will be good.

HTH

Comment: I tried with the DefaultAgendaListener with activationCreated() function overriden and it works great! thank you. Just one more followup, I tried this by loading a simple drl and building a StatefulKnowledgeSession. Say, if I wanted to try this from the ESB's BusinessRuleProcessorAction, how can I get a handle on the session, so I can use the same listener?